# Jquery on document load event only fires occasionally

Tags: jquery, events

I've have pieced together a simple function that adjust the height of some logos when they appear too large in height. The code worked fine the first time I tested it. But now it only works on every 3rd og 4th click. I suspect it has to do with the doc load function vs. the image load, but I am not sure.

```
<script>
// Get on screen image
$( document ).ready(function()

 {
$('#jobcontainer img').each(function() {
      if($(this).height()>50) {
         $(this).addClass('reduceheight')
      }
})

<style>
.reduceheight { width:40%;}
</style>


<table id="jobcontainer" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="dknytliste">
        <td width="138" valign="top" class="dknytliste" style="padding-right:1em;"><p><a href="" class="dknytlink" title=""></a></p></td>
        <td><a href="" class="dknytlink" title=""><img src="" /> </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> </tr>
</table>
```

Check it out here: http://dknyt.dk/forside/index2.php  Its the jobcontainer on the right.

Help would be very much apprciated.

Comment: On what "click", it only loads whenever the page reloads ?

Comment: Document ready and window load are 2 different things.

Comment: @adeneo  Didn't mean click - meant: reload page

Comment: @PatsyIssa Can document-ready be described as "the loading of elements" and window-load as "the presentation of elements"? Or how does it go?

Comment: Document ready waits untill the dom elements are available your markup and tags, window load waits untill all elements are loaded such as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are placing your code in `document.ready`, you should use the loading:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

    $('#jobcontainer img').each(function() {
       if($(this).height()>50) {
         $(this).addClass('reduceheight');
      }
});
```

Also, you have some syntax mistakes. You are forgeting the `;` after `.addClass('reduceheight')` as well as closing the event document ready (now $(window).on('load'...).

Also, you are forgetting the `</script>` closing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document ready which doesn't wait for the images to be loaded use `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('#jobcontainer img').each(function() {
      if($(this).height()>50) {
         $(this).addClass('reduceheight')
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that was quick. Thanks a bunch. Worked like a charm.